# SoLR - How to filter out records which do not have the field value for field listed in SORT?

Tags: solr

In SoLR, We can set sortMissingLast=true on a field in the schema. If the SORT is on this field, it will to push the results which have missing field values to the end.

Is there a way to filter out the results whose sort field values are missing? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict your query to documents that only have a certain field set, add the following parameter to your query:

```
sort_field_name:[* TO *]
```

This will limit the query to only those documents where the sort field exists.

Comment: Thanks John! That solves the issue. So, I added a fq=sort_field_name:[* TO *]. So, this only returns records which have this field value populated. That's cool! Thank you.