# Solr Faceting - ignore fields with no value in facet counts

Tags: java, solr, field, faceted-search

I have an index where some documents are missing a value I am faceting on.  When I run my query, no matter what I do, I get back a count with a blank label for the documents which were empty.

I'm using solrj to query and receive XML back where the element for the empty facet field is present - for example

I do not want to have a a facet count returned back for these empty fields.  I've tried setting facet.missing=false but I still have the count returned.

Does anyone know how to stop this through Solr?  I really want to avoid putting in any logic into my views and to avoid any overhead there is for Solr when counting these.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try to add facet.mincount=1. That will only display facets with a value greater than 1.

Comment: Hi the problem is not with the count as they have a value so mincount is of no use.  It is that the field is blank.  So I end up with a facet count for a blank field.

Comment: I see.... have you looked into querying with a facet prefix? It will only give you counts for items that meet that criteria. I believe you can also use a regular expression in it.

Comment: I think those voteuppers did not understand the question. It is not about filtering facet counts, but facet values. The question is about filtering out empty values from facet results. And I don't think regular expressions work with facet.prefix. Where have you got this information?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24740431/2039709 (include the facet fields as non-empty in your query)